# I need to equalize a text phrase with a numeric value

Tags: google-sheets

So what I need is to make a neat-looking salary-counting spreadsheet, which doesn't show the numeric value in its cells but instead text values. To be specific, my case is I'm a teacher and I have different groups which pay a different sum of money. So the way I imagine it is I somehow link the text and the numbers - i.e. Starters=1200, Movers=1700, Flyers=1700 etc, and when it comes to summing up the values, it can basically go as 'Starters+Movers+Flyers=4600'. I have no clue how to introduce variables in excel/gsheets though, and whether it's even possible.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Don't use it for the Google Drive Excel files editor."_ and the [microsoft-excel] tag description explicitly states _"Questions with this tag should ONLY be about how Microsoft Excel interacts with a specific web application. General questions about Microsoft Excel are off-topic here but can be asked at Super User."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)? You create a table off to the side or on another sheet, then you reference that table using VLOOKUP during the calculation. So instead of `Starters+Movers+Flyers=4600` it look like `ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(A1:A4, costTable, 2, FALSE)`. I can explain more, but please do confirm first if VLOOKUP solves your specific problem.

Comment: @doubleunary Sorry, fixed it

Comment: [Edit] your question to show an example of your data in markdown before and after.  It isn't clear exactly what you want, [@Doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173083) solves the most obvious interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do that is to use [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175).

Put the numbers `1200`, `1700` and `1700` in cells `A2:A4`.

Create a named range `Starters` that points to `A2`.

Create a named range `Movers` that points to `A3`.

Create a named range `Flyers` that points to `A4`.

Then enter a formula like `=Starters + Movers + Flyers` in cell `B2`. The result will be `4600`.

You apparently want to "hide" numbers. To do that, choose **Insert > Sheet**, hide the original sheet, and enter a formula like `=Starters + Movers + Flyers` anywhere in the new sheet. It will give the same result.

Comment: Thank you - but doesn't it do the opposite of what I want? I need to show the text with numbers hidden behind it, while this guide seems to be about turning hidden text values into visible numbers.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a detailed explanation.